# Why cant this situation is possible when we are considering a dimensional analysis approach in any problem?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Suppose a unknown quantity (whose dimension we know) depends on known three quantities like (Length of object L) , (Energy of Object E), (Density of Object D), when we try to get the relation among these four by dimensional analysis , we do like this : letting Unknown = $L^{alpha} * E^{beta} * D ^{gamma}$ we equate the dimensions to solve for alpha ,beta and gamma , but my question is why cant we consider situation where it might be like this : $Unknown(E,D,L)$=$ (E+aE^2 +bE^3...)^{beta} ....$ . Where a , b etc. are such that aE^2 has dimension E , similarily others . Is it not possible to have forms like this ? As such one can observe such type can be seen in mechanics problems where $v = at +bt^2$ etc type problems .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

If you add terms, you do not change the dimensionality of the result. For example, if I add 2 meters to 6 meters ($2 m + 6 m$) the result is still expressed in m (a length). However, if I multiply them, things change. For example, 2 meters by 6 meters ($2m \times6m$) is an area, not a length.

Now consider your example of $ (E+aE^2 +bE^3...)^{beta} ....$

If $E$ had the dimension of $m$, $E^2$ would be an area, $E^3$ would be a volume, etc. It is obvious those things cannot be summed.

Comment: a and b has dimensions of E^-1 , E^-2 respectively , i meant hdhondt

Comment: That still doesn't alter the fact that a factored dimension is a different thing. $1/m$ is **not** a length and $1/m^2$ is **not** an area.

Comment: I mean to say cant we have formulas like v= aT+bT^2 +cT^3 ? dimensional analysis  will just tells its dimensional formula that is of form v=a'T but how exact like the above?

Comment: a,b,c have dimensions such that overall dimension of each term matches v

Comment: Not sure I understand... However, if "overall dimension of each term matches v", then you have something like $v=aT^2+bT^2+cT^2$, which reduces to $v=pT^2$

Comment: Consider v(speed) is a just dependent on two quantities = tangential acc(a) and time(T) , by dimensional analysis we arrived at the form of it to be aT so it would be $v=kaT$ , where k is dimensionless quantity , but why this formula is not possible ? This formula : v = $kaT+(alpha)aT^2 + (beta)a^2T^2$ , where alpha and beta are **constants** having dimension of T^-1  , T^-1a^-1 respectively . Now we can observe that we can only factor out aT common and get aT[k+(alpha)T+(beta)aT] so its a function which is not told by dimensional analysis as...

Comment: ...this one depends on T^2 and T both while the dimensional analysis one gave depends on just T.

Comment: But, $T^2\times T^{-1}=T$ so the entire sum has dimension T

Comment: Yeah dimension is same , i mean this formula we cant get from dimensional analysis isnt?

Comment: It's all the same dimension. As I said in an earlier comment, $v=aT^2+bt^2+CT^2$ reduces to $v=pT^2$, where $p=a+b+c$

Comment: Sir i am saying we know the dimensions (aT) from there we generate a formula for it suppose kaT , but this is not having the formula of kaT+alphaaT^2 ,,, kaT+alphaa^2T^2 ...any of them in cosideration for a actual formula

Comment: I am asking for actual full formula generation not just the dimensional formula

Comment: "full formula generation not just the dimensional formula" - You seem to be changing the question. The dimensional formula is not the same as the actual one.